# Fast way to flatten an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of generated objects like the following:

```
[ 
  {obj1: {
    key: 'value'
  }},
  {obj2: {
    key: 'value2'
  }},
  {obj3: {
    key: 'value3'
  }}
]
```

I would like to flatten the array, with the following output:

```
[ 
  {
    key: 'value'
  },
  {
    key: 'value2'
  },
  {
    key: 'value3'
  }
]
```

I am doing this with a for loop, which works, but the array will be quite large in size and wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this?

```
for (var key in array) {
  let obj = array[key];
  for (var key in obj) { 
    newArray.push(obj[key]);
  }
}

output: 
newArray: [
  {
    key: 'value'
  },
  {
    key: 'value2'
  },
  {
    key: 'value3'
  }
]
```

### I'm looking for the simplest method, ES6 or Lodash also welcome for solutions.

Updated to reflect correct array format.

Comment: You first array is kind of strange : is it an `Array` on wich you assigned special fields (`obj1` etc...) ? Maybe you got it from some php deserialization function ?

Comment: It comes from a firestore query, where I am fetching an array from a document.. The array is basically a map of objects stored in the document.

Comment: The first data structure you show isn't valid JS. Please update your question if it looks different.

Comment: @ogot those need to be in `key/value` pair, `{obj1:{key: 'value}}` like this not `obj:{key:value}`

Comment: `for.. in` is wrong for arrays. Period.

Comment: If the outer object is actually an array, then `for-in` will be slower than a `for` loop. That would be the first thing to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [**Object.values**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
let arr = [{obj1: {key: `value`}},{obj2: {key: `value2`
}},{obj3: {key: `value3`}}]

let op = arr.reduce((op,e)=> op.concat(Object.values(e)),[])

console.log(op)
```

You can use simple `for` loop when you care about speed.

```js
let arr = [{obj1: {key: `value`}},{obj2: {key: `value2`
    }},{obj3: {key: `value3`}}]

let op = []

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  let values = Object.values(arr[i])
  op = op.concat(values)
}

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [Object.values](https://javascript.info/keys-values-entries).

**Map** "maps" each element in an array to a new array.

It takes each element of an array, and performs an operation on it.
The result of this operation becomes the corresponding element in a new Array.
This new Array is what's returned.

To convert **Objects into Arrays**: you can use `Object.values`, `Object.keys`, and `Object.entries`.
`Object.values` de-references each key in an object, and turns it into an array element holding that key's value.

```js
const arr = [ 
  {obj1: {key: 'value'}},
  {obj2: {key: 'value2'}},
  {obj3: {key: 'value3'}}
];

let newArr = arr.map(obj => (
  {key: Object.values(obj)[0].key}
));

console.log(newArr);
```

To return an object, it must be wrapped in parenthesis.

In the first iteration, `obj` == `{ obj1: { key: 'value' }}`, the first element in the input Array, `arr`.

And,

`Object.values(obj)` == `[{key: 'value'}]`

So, we need to grab the element at index `0` to pull the object out of the array `{key: 'value'}`.

Alternatively, if you know you can rely on the naming structure of the elements in your array (the outer object's key), you *could* do this, which may be easier to reason about:

```js
const arr = [ 
  {obj1: {key: 'value'}},
  {obj2: {key: 'value2'}},
  {obj3: {key: 'value3'}}
];

let newArr2 = arr.map( (obj, i) => (
  { key: obj['obj'+(i+1)].key }
));

console.log(newArr2);
```

Note: you'll need to wrap the `i+1` in parenthesis, to force addition to take precedence over JS auto type conversion and string concatenation. Otherwise instead of `obj1, obj2, obj3`, you'll get `obj01, obj11, obj21` as the object keys.